# XSS-Safe URL data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xss

I am making a ASP.NET website where the user inputs some data (into a database) on one page, then it is displayed back to users on another page.

One of my inputs is a URL, and I need it to be XSS-safe when displaying it back to users. I also need it to be a click-able hyperlink.

I think I need to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() somewhere, but not sure if this belongs in the input code or the output code. Help appreciated.

Comment: No responses .... I think what I might have to do is just restrict the user input for the URL with a Regular Expression or similar... Any comments about this issue are appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: So, if anyone is interested, I figured out a solution.

Comment: The solution is...

the <a> tag would look something like:
<a href='GoToURL?url='<%UrlEncode(txt)%>'>HTMLencode(txt)</a>

Then in GoToURL.aspx, just have a decode and redirect...
Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("url")))

I.e, no checks are done on user input. href output is UrlEncoded. The text between <a> and </a> is HTMLencoded. And then the URL is decoded again in server code (not client code).

Hope this helps someone :)